# Underscores in MvvmCross data binding

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm using the fluent syntax and lambdas for data binding in MvvmCross. An example of this is:

```
var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<MyTableCell, MyTableCellViewModel>();
bindings.Bind(titleLabel).To(vm => vm.MY_TITLE);
bindings.Apply();
```

Whenever I try this with an underscore in a view model property I get an exception:

> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Unexpected character _ at
>   position 3 in targetProperty text MY_TITLE

I believe the error message is a result of MvvmCross parsing the data binding, yet this seems to only make sense for people using string-based data binding, not the lambda expression syntax.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the view models so I'm looking for a workaround to allow underscores in the view models. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess this is a general problem in the MvvmCross parser - probably in

```
    private void ParsePropertyName()
    {
        var propertyText = new StringBuilder();
        while (!IsComplete && char.IsLetterOrDigit(CurrentChar))
        {
            propertyText.Append(CurrentChar);
            MoveNext();
        }

        var text = propertyText.ToString();
        CurrentTokens.Add(new MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken(text));
    }
```

In https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Parse/PropertyPath/MvxSourcePropertyPathParser.cs#L80

Which probably needs to be fixed to something like:

```
        while (!IsComplete && 
               (char.IsLetterOrDigit(CurrentChar) || CurrentChar == '_')
```

There are workarounds you could do, but the easiest solution is probably to fix this and rebuild, rather than to try workarounds.

---

But if you do want to try workarounds....

Assuming this is static (non-changing) text and this is just a one-off for now, then one workaround might be to add a property to your cell called `Hack` and to then bind like:

```
 bindings.Bind(this).For(v => v.Hack).To(vm => vm);

 //...

 private MyTableCellViewModel _hack;
 public MyTableCellViewModel Hack
 {
    get { return _hack; }
    set { _hack = value; if (_hack != null) titleLabel.Text = _hack.MY_VALUE; }
 }
```

Another alternative (with the same assumptions) might be to use a value converter -

```
 bindings.Bind(titleLabel).To(vm => vm.MY_TITLE).WithConversion(new WorkaroundConverter(), null);

 // ...

 public class WorkaroundConverter : MvxValueConverter<MyTableCellViewModel, string>
 {
     protected override string Convert(MyTableCellViewModel vm, /*...*/)
     {
         if (vm == null) return null;
         return vm.MY_TITLE;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I pushed a fix to the source code (and a test to make sure it doesn't break again) - see commit linked to https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/461

Comment: Thank you so much, Stuart! Brilliant, as always, and an incredible response time.

Comment: It appears the fix does not address variables that start with an underscore (I know, we have crazy view models). The problem seems to be in `ParseNextToken`.